# Do I have to code both ItemClick and Tapped events?

Tags: gridview, windows-8, touch, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I notice that there is both an ItemClick and a Tapped (and RightTapped) event for the GridView control. Will the ItemClick event only work in response to a Mouse-click, and the Tapped event only work in response to a tap on a touch-enabled device?

I would think they would/should be interchangeable (tapping on a touch-enabled device would equate to clicking on a non-touch-enabled device).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They both handle both events unless they are both coded, in which case they distinguish as you would expect.  So code one, and then if you need touch vs click to do something different then code both.

Comment: So can I assume the same with the RightTapped event - that with non-touch-enabled devices the code will run when the user right-clicks?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes - a right-click on my laptop fires the RightTapped event.